# Replacing text containing particular string in a csv row/column

Tags: python, string, csv, pandas, dataframe

I'm unable to remove \u and associated texts in a **csv** row which doesn't start with these particular characters, ie; \u**.

code :

```
# Removing \u*?
import pandas as pd
reader=pd.read_csv('string_HT.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
for index,row in reader.iterrows(): 
    if  ("\u","\u*?","*?\u") in row['Hashtags'] :
        row['Hashtags'] = " "         

reader.to_csv("string_HT2.csv", index=False)
```

Sample input df :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"Hashtags" : ["#DefendTheLand", "#526f\u696d\u7d39\u4ecb", "#30ac\u30f3\u30c0\u30e0", "#leadership" ]})
```

Sample output :

```
{"Hashtags" : ["#DefendTheLand", " ", " ", "#leadership"]}
```

I know similar questions have been asked and I've gone through most of them and tried implementing all the methods provided by other users but i'm still unable to get it correct. Help would be appreciated.

Note:

I've tried this code in my raw file for initial cleaning.

```
for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    df1['Hashtags'] =df1['Hashtags'].str.strip("u'  ',").str.strip("u'").str.strip("\u*?]").str.strip("u']").str.strip("',")
```

Comment: Is the if statement correct?
Shouldn't the comparison be something like:
`if "\u" in row['Hashtags']:` ?

Comment: @jgmh i guess both are acceptable in python, however I've also tried using `if "*?\u*?" in  row['Hashtags'] :
        row['Hashtags'] = " "`  but to no avail.

Comment: So, if you need to remove every hashtag that contains a special char, you can try something like this:
`for element in a["Hashtags"]:
    is_ok = True
    if any(ord(char)>126 for char in element):
        is_ok = False

    print (element, is_ok)
`
After that you can recreate `row['Hashtags']`